# Azure storage table transactions and rollback?

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I have a delete operation that tries to delete various entries from an Azure storage table. Same table, same partition key.

```
private async Task RemoveNodesAsyc(string rowKey, string partitionId)
{
    var result = this.GetNodes(this.table, rowKey, partitionId);

    foreach (var node in result)
    {
        TableOperation deleteOperation = TableOperation.Delete(node);
        TableResult resultDelete = await table.ExecuteAsync(deleteOperation);
    }
}
```

I would like that in case I am deleting 50 rows, and the row number 47 fails, the changes were rolled back, so that I do not end up with 47 rows deleted and 3 rows hanging there in the ether.

Is there any way to do the above code in a transaction-like mode? I have been googling and I found for example this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309294/transactions-in-azure-table-storage), but [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Performing-Entity-Group-Transactions?redirectedfrom=MSDN) about group entity transactions talks about how to use the Rest API only. Is that functionality even available in C#? How can I say in plain C# something like start transaction, do operations, and commit/rollback by the end?

Comment: The docs you linked to talk about batches, not transactions. In any case you're already using the REST API, whether you do it directly or through a convenience wrapper. Just because the wrapper library doesn't wrap some functionality (are you sure?)  doesn't mean you can't call the API using eg HttpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to do the above code in a transaction like mode?

You should be able to do it using [`TableBatchOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tablebatchoperation?view=azure-dotnet) and [`ExecuteBatchAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executebatchasync?view=azure-dotnet).

Your code would be something like (untested code though):

```
private async Task RemoveNodesAsyc(string rowKey, string partitionId)
{
    var result = this.GetNodes(this.table, rowKey, partitionId);
    TableBatchOperation batch = new TableBatchOperation();
    foreach (var node in result)
    {
        batch.Delete(node);
    }
    TableBatchResult result = await this.table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batch);
}
```